# Async function in React-Native Text Property

Tags: react-native

I have a function that get's a variable from `AsyncStorage`.

```
const cloudCheck = async function() {
  let cloud = await AsyncStorage.getItem('cloud');
    cloud = cloud === 'true';
    return cloud;
}
```

I want to use this to do something like so however since it's a promise I don't know how to do it:

```
<Text className={ cloudCheck == "this" ? "style1" : "stye2" }></Text>
```

Can anyone give me any guidance?

Answer (score 0):

You can call it in the `componentDidUpdate` (you can in the `render` as well but best to avoid it) lifecycle method and then `setState({ cloud })`

after that, in your `render` you can do something like this

```
 const { cloud } = this.state;
 ....
 <Text className={ cloud ? "style1" : "stye2" }></Text>
```